# How to create multiple implicit data collections per organization in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Is there any way to have multiple implicit data collections per organization?
According to the information [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/private_data_tutorial.html?highlight=implicit%20data%20collection#build-a-collection-definition-json-file) it seems only one implicit data collection is provided.
If collection name is the [only](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/private-data-arch.html?highlight=implicit%20data%20collection#referencing-implicit-collections-from-chaincode) differentiating criteria between implicit collections and explicit collections, why just one implicit collection is provided per organization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the documentation, it doesn't look like there's a way to create multiple implicit collections.

As the implicit collection is only accessible by the owning organisation, I'm not sure why you would want multiple of them. You could store different data in the collection without any problem.

I guess if you really wanted to have separate collections, you could always define a new collection which is accessible by a single organisation.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. What exactly should the implicit collections use for?

Comment: They should be used when an organisations wants to store data which cannot be read by other organisations (however, the data can be verified to exist in the collection).